# Nginx, priorizar pastas ao invés do "location /"

Tags: php, framework, nginx, phalcon-php

Eu uso PHP com o framework Phalcon em meus projetos e este é a estrutura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu nginx está assim:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name 123.123.123.123;
    root /var/www/meusite.com.br;

    location @site{
        rewrite ^/public(.+)$ /public/index.php?_url=$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php;
        if ($uri !~ ^/public) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @site;

        location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
            root /var/www/meusite.com.br/public;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Está funcionando certinho, só que agora quando for requisitada uma pasta interna, preciso que o nginx ignore todo o "location /" e execute os mesmos comandos do "location /", porém dentro da pasta requisitada. Por exemplo /v2/.

Como faço isso? Já tentei de várias formas. Já procurei no Google. Enfim, o meu maior problema está sendo porque o Phalcon usa uma estrutura de pastas diferente do comum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nginx trabalha ordem da configuração de cima para baixo, ou seja resumindo você tem que colocar as location da pasta que você deseja acessar acima do location / ou você inseri um rewrite dentro do location ordme de cima para baixo.

Exemplo:

```
server {
listen   80;

server_name 123.123.123.123;
root /var/www/meusite.com.br;

location @site{
    rewrite ^/public(.+)$ /public/index.php?_url=$1 last;
}
```

> ```
> location /pastaserchecadaprimeiro {
>   root /var/www/html/pastaserchecadaprimeiro;
> }
> ```

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    if ($uri !~ ^/public) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /public$1;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ @site;

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root /var/www/meusite.com.br/public;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}